# How do you combine multiple spatial functions in one query?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I want to find out the intersection and difference in the same query using postgresql.

How can I combine both st_intersect and st_Difference in same query and return the result.I want to compute the union without using ST_Union function.I want to find union only using intersection and difference.

I have two tables - table1 and table2,  both table consists of a the_geom column. the_geom column has a polygon stored in it. Each table has one polygon stored in it.

I want to compute the union without using ST_Union function.I want to find union only using intersection and difference.

I used st_intersection :

```
select 1 as keys,(st_intersection(tale1.the_geom,table2.the_geom)) from table1,table2

 keys |                                                                      st_intersection
----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | 01030000000100000004000000000000000000F03F000000000000E03F0000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F03F000000000000E03F
(1 row)
```

And when I used difference

select 1 as keys,(st_difference(tale1.the_geom,table2.the_geom)) from table1,table2

I get output as:

```
 keys |                                                                       st_d
ifference

----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-
  1 | 01030000000100000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000F03F000000000000F03F000000000000E03F00000000000000000000000000000000
(1 row)
```

How can I combine the above to query like : st_intersection + st_difference?

I tried :

```
select 1 as keys,(st_intersection(table1.the_geom,table2.the_geom)) from table1,table2 UNION select ,st_difference(table1.the_geom,table2.the_geom) from table1,table2;
```

But it returned an error saying error after select ^ ,st_difference(....

Comment: I'm confused by what you think this will do. First fix the typo (tale1) in the ST_Intersection. The show each of the two individual queries (e.g. intersection and difference) you want; and the results of those queries. Then tell us what you want to do instead.

Comment: Sorry , I have added some content above.I want to compute the union without using ST_Union function.I want to find union only using intersection and difference.

Comment: Please do it as I asked. Show a intersection query that does what you want, then show a difference query that does what you want, then tell us what else you want. I know you know what you want, but I'm not able to understand you yet.

Comment: PLease see the edited content above!

Comment: So you want the keys and the combined geometry?

Comment: Yes , Keys is just a id to identify the row. I would want the union of two polygons(hope thats what combined means).

Comment: Are you just prohibited from using ST_Union? Is ST_Relate OK?

Comment: ya I am prohibited to use St_union. I have to only use st_intersection and st_difference. Challenging right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18612/discussion-between-rdvsm-and-bradhards).

Comment: Its only challenging because you're not providing the detail. Maybe this is a homework problem? Can you use ST_Relates? Maybe ST_Collect? Perhaps I should leave you to it...

Comment: I have answered this on SO, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26900897/how-to-combine-two-spatial-functions-in-one-union-query, before realizing that this was a sock puppet for rdvsm and yet another unrevealed homework question.

Comment: @Rdvsm Please be aware that [GIS SE does not have a policy against homework](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3423/how-to-treat-a-please-do-my-homework-for-me-question) but its users sometimes exercise downvoting when they see no sign of research on questions, irrespective of whether they are homework.

Comment: @PolyGeo. I have no issue with homework, so long as some minimal effort has been made, but I do have an issue with simply pasting the assignment question into stack exchange, something that has happened a few times in the last week. This particular question is the least eggregious in this regard, but was the straw the broke the camel's back, so to speak.

Comment: @JohnBarça I agree with you - when I see minimalist questions I'll often sound out more details before I commit any effort to answering - if no engagement results then I think downvoting as a deterrent can be positive for the site.

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo code:

```
union (A, B) = combination of 
    difference (A, B),
    difference (B, A),
    intersect (A, B)
```

In other words, the union of two regions is the combination of their symmetric difference and their intersection.

To actually do the combination, use [ST_Collect()](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html) which

> is in general orders of magnitude faster than ST_Union because it does not try to dissolve boundaries or validate that a constructed MultiPolgon doesn't have overlapping regions.

Comment: Yes, I was having the same idea.However I am not able to write a sql query which combines this and returns me the_geom value of union

Comment: Yes it is a combination of symmetrical difference , Can you tell me how can form a query where I could use Collect(Intersection and Symdifference)?

Comment: Follow the link for collect() and see similar help for the the others.

Comment: Don't put the *outer* parentheses in    
    (st_difference(tale1.the_geom,table2.the_geom))